# Optimizing a Distance Function Query - SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, function

I wrote a function to calculate the distance between 2 points given a max radius. The function works but needs to be called twice, the way I implemented it:

Once in the select block and then again in the where block.

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Thanks for helping!

```
select
    c.LABEL_NAME,
    k.*,
    dbo.kiw_GetNearMeetingLocationInMiles_FUNC(41.056466,-85.3312009,LATITUDE,LONGITUDE) as distance
    from USR_KIW_CUS_MEETING as k
    join CUSTOMER as c
    on c.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID = k.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID
    where c.USR_MEMBERSHIP_STATUS_CODE NOT IN('CR','CSD')
    and dbo.kiw_GetNearMeetingLocationInMiles_FUNC(41.056466,-85.3312009,LATITUDE,LONGITUDE)  <= 120;
```

UPDATE

This works, based on a suggestion from Mathieu Rodic

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        c.LABEL_NAME,
        k.*,
        dbo.kiw_GetNearMeetingLocationInMiles_FUNC(41.056466,-85.3312009,LATITUDE,LONGITUDE) as distance
    FROM
        USR_KIW_CUS_MEETING as k
    JOIN
        CUSTOMER as c on c.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID = k.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID
    WHERE
        c.USR_MEMBERSHIP_STATUS_CODE NOT IN('CR','CSD')
)a
WHERE
   a.distance <= 120
```

Comment: `with (query minus last line) as withDistance select * from withDistance where distance <= 120;` See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        c.LABEL_NAME,
        k.*,
        dbo.kiw_GetNearMeetingLocationInMiles_FUNC(41.056466,-85.3312009,LATITUDE,LONGITUDE) as distance
    FROM
        USR_KIW_CUS_MEETING as k
    JOIN
        CUSTOMER as c on c.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID = k.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID
    WHERE
        c.USR_MEMBERSHIP_STATUS_CODE NOT IN('CR','CSD')
) AS computed_table
WHERE
    distance <= 120
```

The `HAVING` clause allows to filter by computed columns.

Comment: Hi Mathieu - SQL Error: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Invalid column name 'distance'.

Comment: Thanks - Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

Comment: Well, we went to the same idea at the same time... just a missing alias!

Comment: Mathieu, your suggestion was close. I aliased the sub select and it worked. I am giving you credit because your suggestion led to the solution.